# javascript keyword search

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I only search 1 keywordName (ie: "macc") the program works, it opens 1 new tab. 
When I search 2 words ie: "miller macc" I get an infinite loop of opening tabs. someone help!!!

```
var keywordName = "miller macc";
var split = keywordName.split(" ");
var tFunction = "twitterScan()";
var tweet = new Array();
var tweetName = new Array();

var t;

function twitterScan() {
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    tweetName[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;
    tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;

    var tweetMatch = tweet[0].match(split[i]);
    if (tweetMatch != null && tweetMatch == split[i]) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();
        clearTimeout(t);
    } else {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}
}
t = setTimeout(tFunction, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see possible infinite loop if the code is in content script and the first loop calls          `document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();`

but the second loop calls
`location.reload(true);`

which causes the whole content script to start again and repeat the loop (calling click and then reload again and again).

Comment: the location.reload is to refresh the page if the if statement is not met. somewhere when the if statement is met, Im getting a infinite loop of the code opening new tabs.

Comment: i think your 'statement is met' for i = 0 and 'not met' for i = 1, which would explain the infinite loop. Try to comment out that line

Comment: im sorry, where are you talking about?